# using ngIf to check array length or content to display div

Tags: angular

I would like to control whether to display my div or not depending on the length of the data array. if there is data go ahead and show the div and if not then just hide it. I am using *ngIf but i wanted to ask about two different ways and if one is better than the other and maybe why.

```
*ngIf="dataArray?"
```

or

```
*ngIf="dataArray?.length > 0"
```

Comment: second one and you might want to put that logic into component and expose just the final boolean property to the template. its not necessary but its a good practice especially if your how/hide logic might change and become more complicated.

Comment: *ngIf="dataArray.length > 0" this can be work for you please check this

Comment: @deezg when you mean that i put the logic in the component what would it look like? `public hasData: dataArray?.length > 0;` will this work and then in my html i will just have `*ngIf="hasData"`?

Comment: too long for comments so i've put it in answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To answer your question, the functionality that you want to achieve can be done by using second way:

```
*ngIf="dataArray?.length > 0"
```

since this is really testing if array exists and its length is more than zero (as mentioned by Sajeetharan in his answer).

It also be written in following two different ways to achieve the same result:

```
*ngIf="dataArray?.length"
```

or

```
*ngIf="!!dataArray?.length"
```

The first alternative, uses the fact that array length cannot be less than 0 and 0 is *falsy* and >0 is *truthy*. The second alternative explicitly converts the truthy/falsy states to true or false.

I will prefer to write it this way:

```
*ngIf="dataArray?.length"
```

While writing JS, I tend to write code that is concise and end up doing a trade-off between readability and compactness. This is primarily because JS is interpreted language and concise code give you more efficiency.

I agree there are minifiers available which do that for us, but there are some cases where they may not work like template expressions.

**Moving to component:** That is where Angular starts. I'd say this really depends on the trade-offs and there is no YES-No answer. For our current large Angular4 application that I am working on, we are not moving these. But if there are some additional conditions or involve even slightly more logic, we move it component and set up a flag. So, to answer your question, if you really want to optimize this further, then you can use a flag instead and in the place where elements are added to array, set it to true.

That's how I understand it. If anyone has more to add or correct, please write in comments.

Comment: I really appreciate the explanation. Also would you recommend to moving the logic to the component or will it not have that much of a change?

Comment: No problem. I just edited my answer to add my comments on this part. Hope this helps! If yes, do accept the answer please... :)

Answer (score 1):

The first one

```
*ngIf="dataArray"
```

checks if the element is defined or not.

```
*ngIf="dataArray?.length > 0"
```

this one checks if the element exists and the length of values inside as well.

you should do the 2nd way.

Comment: dataArray only i meant

Answer (score 1):

[continuing from comments]
I can imagine down the road that you might have a need, for example, not to show element if there are elements in array but no elements that have `propertyX > 7` or any other condition. So, for general case, you would want to have boolean property on your component and put that to `*ngIf`.

Something like:

```
export class YourComponent{
  myArray:[];
  shouldShowMyDiv:boolean;

  private procesCondition(){
    this.shouldShowMyDiv = this.myArray.whateverconditions....
  }
}
```

and in template:

```
<div *ngIf="shouldShowMyDiv">...</div>
```

now, it depends how&when you get your array. If its static, you can call `procesCondition` in components `ngOnInit` and if its observable, you would want to check it in `ngOnChanges` hook.

Answer (score 0):

*ngIf="dataArray?"
=> this checks whether dataArray is defined or not (Not preferable in your case)
or

*ngIf="dataArray?.length > 0"
=>this checks whether dataArray is defined or not and (Preferable in your case)

- if defined then get the length
- Then check the length is greater than 0 or not. if greater than ZERO then show the div

The 2nd one is good practice to always check if the varible is defined or not