# How to show an element in Angular 7 only if another element has no children

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework

I have a simple angular 7 code whose general structure is like this:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of items">
   <ion-item *ngIf="item.isReachable()">
       ......
   </ion-item>
</ng-container>
<ion-item id="target" *ngIf="ng-container has no children">
    <ion-label>
        Text to show only if ng-container has no children
    </ion-label>
</ion-item>
```

May anyone tell me how I can show `target` element only if `<ng-container>` has no children?
What is the condition that I have to write inside the `*ngIf` to obtain this effect?

`items` is a non-empty array, so I cannot write a condition like this `*ngIf="items.length == 0"` to obtain what I want. The `target` element should be shown only if all elements of `items` array don't satisfy the `isReachable()` condition, so only if `<ng-container>` has no children.

Is there a way to write this simply inside the `*ngIf` condition?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using ngIf to check array length or content to display div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46883154/using-ngif-to-check-array-length-or-content-to-display-div)

Comment: Don't focus on the container, what you actually want to know is if `items` is empty or not as this is what displays the data in the container

Comment: you can have a filter logic in class and use that, simple

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep it in JS, you can use a getter like so :

```
get hasChildren() {
  return this.items.some(item => item.isReachable());
}
```

For the template

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of items">
   <ion-item *ngIf="item.isReachable()">
       ......
   </ion-item>
</ng-container>
<ion-item id="target" *ngIf="!hasChildren">
    <ion-label>
        Text to show only if ng-container has no children
    </ion-label>
</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use just CSS to do that :

```css
.items-container {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 12px;
}

.items-container:not(:empty) + ion-item {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="items-container">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of items">
     <ion-item *ngIf="item.isReachable()">
         Here should be the items
     </ion-item>
  </ng-container>
</div>
<ion-item id="target" *ngIf="ng-container has no children">
    <ion-label>
        This text should not be displayed
    </ion-label>
</ion-item>

<div class="items-container"></div>
<ion-item id="target" *ngIf="ng-container has no children">
    <ion-label>
        Text to show only if ng-container has no children
    </ion-label>
</ion-item>
```

I added an items container for style, but also because you need an element to use the CSS selector (and `ng-container`s aren't rendered).

Answer (score 0):

What you need is just put the "if "logic one level above the ng-container

```html
<div *ngIf="items.isThereAnyItemUnreachable(); else target">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of items">
     <ion-item *ngIf="item.isReachable()">
         ......
     </ion-item>
  </ng-container>
</div>
<ng-template #target>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>
        Text to show only if ng-container has no children
    </ion-label>
</ion-item>
</ng-template>
```